# How to append stderr to log_failure_msg in init.d script

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04, scripts, python

To my understanding, in /lib/lsb/init.functions, `log_failure_msg` is the proper way to output a failure message to some log file. I was wondering if it were possible to do this.

```
python some/script/here.py 2>> log_failure_msg
```

log_failure_msg is usually used like so `log_failure_msg "some failure message"`

I have my doubts that this would not work as I hope with the stderr being the message passed to log_failure_msg. I would test this out but I am also not sure where this newly created log file is placed. If anyone could assist or offer an alternative to how to log my error with log_failure_msg then I would great appreciate it.

One more thing. Right after my python line, I have `retval=$?`. I need this line to be right after my python command so I can capture the return code. I couldn't think of anyway to grab the stderr and assign it to a variable that I could pass to log_failur_msg due to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you check the specification of [log_failure_msg](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html), it says:

```
log_failure_msg message

    The log_failure_msg function shall cause the system to write a failure
    message to an unspecified log file. The format of the message is
    unspecified.The log_failure_msg function may also write a message to the
    standard output.

    Note: The message should be relatively short; no more than 60 characters
    is highly desirable.
```

So it looks like the function only writes to `standard output` not `standard error`. This is way a `2> somewhere` will not work.

On the other hand, if you want a Python script to write to `stderr`, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python/15808105) will tell you how. The `log_failure_msg` is only for **Shell scripts** and is typically sourced:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /lib/lsb/init-functions
log_failure_msg "some error"
```

Combining the Python and Shell error reporting doesn't seam like a good idea.

Comment: The purpose of my shell script was to relaunch the py script if something causes it to crash. I want to capture that stderror that contains the reason the py script terminated. Since this does seem to be the case because log_failure_msg only seems to take predefined messages and not stderror I'll just use my original python line used in my question and output to a log file. Thanks